# Is there a JavaScript equivalent of the Python pass statement that does nothing?

Tags: javascript, python, function, lexical

I am looking for a JavaScript equivalent of the Python:

`pass` statement that does not run the function of the `...` notation?

**Is there such a thing in JavaScript?**

Comment: Isn't `{}` empty braces the same thing ?

Comment: @sagarchalise that is true

Comment: `null` is sometimes used for that, as in `if (condition) null;`

Comment: You literally don't need one. If you want, just add a comment. But really, in JavaScript you just leave it completely empty.

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Python's `pass` mainly exists because in Python whitespace matters within a block. In Javascript, the equivalent would be putting nothing within the block, i.e. `{}`.

Answer (score 78):

use `//pass` like python's `pass`

like:

```
if(condition){
   //pass
}
```

This is equivalent to leaving the block with nothing in it, but is good for readability reasons.

reference from https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-empty

Comment: when newlines are stripped incorrectly from HTML  // double slash comments get to comment everything after it. its better to use /*  */ than slash

Comment: nice solution, right here. KISS

Answer (score 22):

python's [pass](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/pass.html) is required for empty blocks.

```
try:
    # something
except Exception:
    pass
```

In javascript you can simply catch an empty block

```
try {
    // some code
} catch (e) {
    // This here can be empty
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Javascript does not have a python `pass` equivalent, unfortunately.

For example, it is not possible in javascript to do something like this:

`process.env.DEV ? console.log('Connected..') : pass`

Instead, we must do this:

`if (process.env.DEV) console.log('Connected..')`

The advantage of using the `pass` statement, among others, is that in the course of the development process we can evolve from the above ternary operator example in this case without having to turn it into a full `if` statement.

Comment: This works exactly the same way in Python, you can't use `pass` in a conditional expression, you would have to use a conditional statement

Answer (score 6):

you could create a function that actually does nothing.

```
const pass = () => {}
```

```
try {
  pass()
} else {
  console.log('helloworld!')
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old question but i guess that is also possible to do something like this. 
You can declare a constant that contains a string (or something else).

```
const pass = 'pass';
```

`const pass = null;` may also be good.

```
if (condition) {
   pass
} else {
   console.log('hi!');
}
```

However note also that this may be a better option.

```
if (condition) {}
else {
    console.log('cool!');
}
```

Python doesn't have brackets to determine where the blocks of code are like javascript, so an empty block throws error (that's why you put the `pass` statement in empty blocks). What i have done by answering this question is just creating a constant using it as if it was a statement. The concept is really near to python's substitution of pass with ellipsis. 
Someone in python prefers to use `...` instead of `pass`.

```
if condition:
    ...
else:
    print('Python!')
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases `pass` can just be `;`

A real life example can be:

```
var j;
for (j = i + 1; j < binstrN.length && binstrN[j] != 1; j++) {
}
let count = j - i;
```

is same as

```
var j;
for (j = i + 1; j < binstrN.length && binstrN[j] != 1; j++);
let count = j - i;
```

Here we are trying to move `j` to next '1', while `i` was already at a '1' before it, hence `count` gives the distance between first two '1's in the string binary string `binstrN`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just use the pass operator in a ternary operator or just in an if statement in JS, you can do this:

```
a === true && (console.log('okay'))
```

You can also use the opposite of &**&** which is the **||** operator. Then if you want to use Pass in a function or a block in general as we do in Python like this:

```
def Func(): pass
```

In JS if it's an if/else statement, you don't need to have that block at all that would pass, you just don't add it:

```
if(condition) {
  console.log('ok')
}
/* else {} remove it! /
```

And if it's a function that you are planning to implement later, you can throw an error inside it, that way if you use it, you get a nice error that reminds you to implement it.

```
function getUser() {
 throw "Not Implemented Yet";
}
```

In the end, there are no braces in Python, which is why we have a pass.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way for passing an if statement is entering a string. 'pass' is more readible.

```js
if(true){
'pass'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that I get an error with empty braces, instead I put a semicolon in there, basically the same thing:

```
try { //something; } catch (err) { ; }
```

Comment: What error do you get with empty braces with no semicolon inside?

Comment: when newlines are stripped incorrectly from HTML // double slash comments get to comment everything after it. its better to use /* */ than slash like that